# Listview returns empty

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Good day, I'm trying to build a book shelf with a horizontal list inside a list view but when the app runs, the listview is blank.
What am i missing? 
Here's my code (and some code from a tutorial which i was using as a guide)

ListBook.java

```
public class ListBooks extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;
    private VerticalAdapter verListAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_books);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listbooks);
        BookItem book1 = new BookItem("Fist of Fury");
        BookItem book2 = new BookItem("Fist of the fists");
        BookItem book3 = new BookItem("Enders game");
        BookItem book4 = new BookItem("Lovers");

        ArrayList<BookItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<BookItem>();
        arrayList.add(book1);
        arrayList.add(book2);
        ArrayList<BookItem> list = new ArrayList<BookItem>();
        list.add(book3);
        list.add(book4);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> group = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>();
        group.add(arrayList);
        group.add(list);
        verListAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_book_list, group);
        listView.setAdapter(verListAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_books, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private class VerticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<BookItem>> {
        private int resource;

        public VerticalAdapter(Context _context, int _ResourceId,
                               ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> _items) {
            super(_context, _ResourceId, _items);
            this.resource = _ResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                rowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resource,
                        null);
            } else {
                rowView = convertView;
            }

            HorizontalListView hListView = (HorizontalListView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.sublistview);
            HorizontalAdapter horListAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(
                    getContext(), R.layout.listitem, getItem(position));
            hListView.setAdapter(horListAdapter);

            return rowView;
        }
    }

   private class HorizontalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookItem> {

        private int resource;

        public HorizontalAdapter(Context _context, int _textViewResourceId,
                                 ArrayList<BookItem> _items) {
            super(_context, _textViewResourceId, _items);
            this.resource = _textViewResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    this.resource, null);

            TextView topText = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);


            topText.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());


            return retval;
        }
    }

}
```

Layout files
Listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/wood"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_book_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.azed">


    <com.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/sublistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ddd"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_list_books.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.azed">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listbooks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check if your `adapter.getCount()` returns more than 0?

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes. it returns a count of 2.

Comment: Ok, but you got to check in both adapters. Also, apply colored backgrounds to your items so you know they are there, for testing purposes.

Comment: @joao2fast4u i have checked both adapters and they both contain data. When i step through the code, everything seems fine except the final list view is blank.

Comment: If you have data and your `getView()` method is being called, try to set a fixed height value on your `HorizontalListView` in the XML.

Comment: Since you don't use a lot of code that is of the ArrayAdapter, you can extend BaseAdapter instead. All that you need is to implement getCount() and getItem.